# Mapping within JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it not possible to map data in side html in a function. I get following result:

[image]

When using this code:

```
const RenderJobsTable = crawl => {
  return (
    <table className="table table-responsive-sm table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Username</th>
          <th>Date registered</th>
          <th>Role</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        crawl.crawl.jobsList.map(status => (
        <tr>
          <td>Yiorgos Avraamu</td>
          <td>2012/01/01</td>
          <td>Member</td>
          <td style={{ width: 20, cursor: "pointer" }}>
            <Dropdown
              toggle={() => {
                toggleMenu(crawl);
              }}
              isOpen={crawl.toggleDropdown}
            >
              <DropdownToggle tag="div">&bull;&bull;&bull;</DropdownToggle>
              <DropdownMenu>
                <DropdownItem onClick={() => toggleCrawlResultModal("")}>
                  Result
                </DropdownItem>
                <DropdownItem onClick={() => alert("dd")}>
                  Analytics
                </DropdownItem>
                <DropdownItem onClick={toggleAIModal}>Insights</DropdownItem>
                <DropdownItem onClick={toggleDetails}>Details</DropdownItem>
              </DropdownMenu>
            </Dropdown>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Avram Tarasios</td>
          <td>2012/02/01</td>
          <td>Staff</td>
          <td>&bull;&bull;&bull;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Quintin Ed</td>
          <td>2012/02/01</td>
          <td>Admin</td>
          <td>&bull;&bull;&bull;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Enéas Kwadwo</td>
          <td>2012/03/01</td>
          <td>Member</td>
          <td>&bull;&bull;&bull;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Agapetus Tadeáš</td>
          <td>2012/01/21</td>
          <td>Staff</td>
          <td>&bull;&bull;&bull;</td>
        </tr>
        ));
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};
```

Comment: You have forgotten `{` before `crawl.crawl.jobsList.map(status => (` and `}` after `));` in your code

Comment: Wrap your map function in {}

Comment: Artem you were first can you add an answer. Thanks both of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JSX you have to embed your map within curly braces `{}` to work. Please find the official documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#embedding-map-in-jsx). Your code should be something like 
`

```
<tbody>
        {crawl.crawl.jobsList.map(status => (
        <tr>
          <td>Yiorgos Avraamu</td>
          <td>2012/01/01</td>
          <td>Member</td>
          <td style={{ width: 20, cursor: "pointer" }}>
            <Dropdown
              toggle={() => {
                toggleMenu(crawl);
              }}
              isOpen={crawl.toggleDropdown}
            >
              <DropdownToggle tag="div">&bull;&bull;&bull;</DropdownToggle>
              <DropdownMenu>
                <DropdownItem onClick={() => toggleCrawlResultModal("")}>
                  Result
                </DropdownItem>
                <DropdownItem onClick={() => alert("dd")}>
                  Analytics
                </DropdownItem>
                <DropdownItem onClick={toggleAIModal}>Insights</DropdownItem>
                <DropdownItem onClick={toggleDetails}>Details</DropdownItem>
              </DropdownMenu>
            </Dropdown>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Avram Tarasios</td>
          <td>2012/02/01</td>
          <td>Staff</td>
          <td>&bull;&bull;&bull;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Quintin Ed</td>
          <td>2012/02/01</td>
          <td>Admin</td>
          <td>&bull;&bull;&bull;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Enéas Kwadwo</td>
          <td>2012/03/01</td>
          <td>Member</td>
          <td>&bull;&bull;&bull;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Agapetus Tadeáš</td>
          <td>2012/01/21</td>
          <td>Staff</td>
          <td>&bull;&bull;&bull;</td>
        </tr>
        ));}
      </tbody>
```

`